# passing model in Url.action through anchor tag in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need pass model to particular action result by using Url.action as href in anchor tag. Please refer below code

```
trend is data table
//sc is SurVeyModel
    foreach (DataRow dr in trend.Rows)
                {
                    // Url.Action(
                    surveyId = dr["Survey_Id"].ToString();
                    vin = dr["VIN"].ToString();


                    var url = Url.Action("Index", "../corporate/surveysummary", new { surveyId = dr["Survey_Id"].ToString(), VIN = dr["VIN"].ToString(),criteria=sc });
                    dr["VIN"] = "<a href= '" + url + "'>" + vin + "</a>";
                }
```

it give url like

```
"/corporate/surveysummary?surveyId=1330511000013&VIN=JN8AZ08W94W339992&criteria=Models.SurveyModel"
```

it doesn't correct i need to pass entire model via Url.action through anchor tag.

how can i ?

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: "/corporate/surveysummary?surveyId=..." equals to "/corporate/surveysummary/Index?surveyId=...", Right?

Comment: yes. am sking model  to pass in Url.action

Comment: It's the default the framework omit the action in address, when is the same specified as default in RouteConfig

Comment: i am not asking this one am asking how can i pass class(model) in Url.action

Comment: wait? You want to pass model data via url? You cannot! It's GET HTTP methods. You only can call the action with model when you call page by POST!! They are different HTTP Methods!

Comment: the only way I am aware is to build the call through ajax.  If you don't want to build the model that way I would recommend just passing the id to the controller and recreating the model there.

Comment: You want the contents of Model.Survey to pass as query string?If i am not wrong!

Comment: matt-i can't get you. what you are saying "the only way I am aware is to build the call through ajax" how it possible?